# Cómo imprimir en consola un link que conduzca a determinada linea de un archivo, como cuando se produce un error

Tags: java, eclipse

Cómo imprimir en consola un link que conduzca a determinada linea de un archivo en Eclipse, como sucede cuando se produce un error.

[image: Mensaje de error de Java en la consola del entorno de desarrollo integrado Eclipse]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que sale en consola es interpretado por Eclipse, el link no es generado por la aplicación. Si escribes un texto que siga el formato
`<paquete>.<Clase>.<metodo>(<Clase>.java:<numero_entero>)`, Eclipse automáticamente lo interpreta como un enlace a dicha clase. Por ejemplo:

```java
package main;

public class MainTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main.MainTest.main(MainTest.java:2)");

    }

}
```

generará lo siguiente:

[image: enlace generado]

El texto en tu ejemplo sale rojo porque usa `System.err` en lugar de `System.out`, es una distinción que también elige hacer el IDE para avisar del origen del texto, en la línea de comandos seguramente no se vea esa diferencia.